# Sql file changed its name to local, when tried to see what is inside it. Why did this happen

Tags: mysql, sql, file

I wanted to see what was in my sql file, because I thought it was empty.
Now, soon as I did that, it changed its name automatically to local.
Would anybody know why that is, and how can I fix it.
The file is located in app folder, then in sql folder next to public folder.

Comment: Please Add SQL type like postgresql , MSSQL or MYSQL and what do you mean by sql file is it SQL query file or the SQL database data file . Please add any screenshots if possible

Comment: Its the file that holds database info. Here is what is inside it.:

Comment: Its the file that holds database info. Here is some code inside it: I can't 

show you all the data, its too much:  MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.16, for 

Win64 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: ::1    Database: local
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version 8.0.16

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;